# How do I do extract information from two different indices in two different data frames in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames of different length:

```
      Df1                     Df2    
      11    A12               11    B72
      11    E17               12    F15
      11    B72               13    C12
      11    E15  
      11    C12
      11    B2
      43    C11
```

I am trying to do a `for` loop to count all the rows in `Df1` until the value of index `1` appears in `Df2`, but only as long as index `0` in `Df2` matches index `0` in `Df1`. I then want to save what was counted and do the loop over.

I have tried a variety of for-while-if loops but nothing really works, this is where I have gotten stuck(sorry for the horrible formatting):

```
     for row_i in range(len(Df2)):
         one_Df2=(Df2.iloc[row_i,1,])
         two_Df2=((int(df.iloc[row_i,0,])))
         for row_ii in range(len(df1)):  
             one_Df1=(df.iloc[row_ii,1,])
             two_Df1=((int(df.iloc[row_ii,0,])))
                  if two_Df1==two_Df2: 
                      if aoi_row_iiii is not aoi_row_iii:
                          counter_2=counter_2+1#--> count +1        
                      else:
                          Df3.append(counter_2)
                          counter_2=0
```

However this nested for-loop in the beginning makes a stack overflow, and nothing happens. If I do them one by one and print it works fine. Can anyone help a hopeless beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess a bit since you didn't provide an output for your example (also try to provide the data in source code, so that its easily applicable by other people for testing purposes).

In any case try and see if the following recipe does what you wish. It relies on nested loops and `if` statements for what seems to be your criteria:

```
df1 = np.array([['11', 'A12'],
                ['11', 'E17']
                , ['11', 'B72']
                , ['11', 'E15']
                , ['11', 'C12']
                , ['11', 'B2']
                , ['12', 'F15']
                , ['12', 'C12']
                , ['12', 'B2']
                , ['13', 'C13']
                , ['13', 'B2']
                , ['13', 'F15']
                , ['13', 'C12']
                , ['43', 'C11']])

df2 = np.array([['11', 'B72'],
                ['12', 'F15']
                , ['13', 'C12']])

counter = []
for i in range(df2.shape[0]):
    counter.append(0)
    for j in range(df1.shape[0]):
        if df1[j, 0] == df2[i, 0]:
            if df1[j, 1] != df2[i, 1]:
                counter[-1] += 1
            elif df1[j, 1] == df2[i, 1]:
                counter[-1] += 1
                break

print(counter)
```

, the result is this:

```
[3, 1, 4]
```

I've added a few more points to your `df1` in order to test check if every criteria was followed the way I interpreted it from your OP. Notice also the use of `break` to stop the loop once one of the stop criteria is achieved.

I used numpy arrays since it seemed similar enough to what you were doing in your code (although I suspect you are using pandas; might want to put that in the tags if that is the case). The arrays are all strings, that is why I'm never converting anything to numbers. The equality will work just the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and patience. And thanks for the question-writing tips! Is there an advantage to using "break" over "range(len(df))?

Comment: @Aggis The break stops the inner loop and as so stops the counter from moving forward. Once the break appears the the outside loop will process the next index for df2. In this case the break is essential for the algorithm to work. In others you might want to use it when you want to stop a loop (for instance you have already done everything you need in the list, no need to loop it until the end and thus saves resources and increases speed).